# How do you disable Printer Sharing via terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I am looking for a command/script to disable the printing sharing feature via terminal. Does anyone have any idea or know how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4):

According to `cupsctl`'s man page:

```
cupsctl --no-share-printers
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `lpstat -v` to get the appropriate printer name, then use:

```
lpadmin -p Printer_Name -o printer-is-shared=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable Printer Sharing: all printers

```
for printer in $(lpstat -p|awk '{ print $2}')
do
  lpadmin -p $printer -o printer-is-shared=false
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the /usr/sbin/cupsdisable command.

```
mgagnon-mbp:~ mgagnon$ lpstat -p

printer c360 is idle.  enabled since Thu Mar 26 16:27:59 2015

mgagnon-mbp:~ mgagnon$ cupsdisable c360

mgagnon-mbp:~ mgagnon$ lpstat -p
printer c360 disabled since Thu Mar 26 16:29:08 2015 -
    Paused

mgagnon-mbp:~ mgagnon$ cupsenable c360

mgagnon-mbp:~ mgagnon$ lpstat -p
printer c360 is idle.  enabled since Thu Mar 26 16:29:16 2015
```

Comment: Doesn't that stop/start the printer entirely? Rather than just turning sharing off/on?

Comment: Alistair, yes cupsdisable stops the printer for everyone. I should have paid closer attention to question! Thanks.